# Google Apps Script web application down with no error messages

Tags: google-apps-script

The web application has been running fine with no pushes to live site for three weeks and is suddenly not working.  There are no error messages.

The /exec live site is not working.

The /dev site was working but as soon as I saved a change to it, it stopped working.

A national team relies on this application daily.

What are my options for troubleshooting?

Is there a place to view status for this service?

The app is provided through Google Apps for business.

(Edit:  For context, as a developer I don't have access to support for Google Apps (but the IT department do and aren't open for a few hours), hence this query to see what others had done to troubleshoot in a similar situation)

Comment: You should use the G Suite support services: [GSuite Support Information](https://gsuite.google.com/support/)  Stack Overflow is not for reporting service disruptions.  You can also mention this in the [Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)  If someone can isolate the line or a few lines of code that is causing the problem, then you may be able to get free help or advice.  Because the Web App was previously working, it could be a service disruption or a bug.  You can check the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open)

Comment: Probably, google.scritp.init function don't work because browse cache. Workaround: Browser cache disabled.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, unfortunately it didn't have effect.

Comment: What happens when you run the application as the owner from within apps scripts? Your error could be a problem with authentication tokens. A script can appear to go down inexplicably if a new service is called with a script that it doesn't have permission. Some admin actions can also take a script down, such as requiring a password change on the next login by the account running the script (I did that one to myself).

Comment: Thank you for suggestions.  `Publish > Deploy as web app > Execute the app as...` is set to `me`, I'm not quite sure what you mean by `run the application as the owner from within apps scripts`.  Did you mean run a function from within the apps script editor interface?  `Code.gs` contains many functions.